# Why does this ng-click not work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Im using `angular` with the `ui-bootstrap` module installed and I am using this `modal` and I want a button that has a `ng-click` directive but when i click it nothing happens.

Heres my code

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="profileModal.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">Profile</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" ng-bind-html="content">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="close()">Cancel</button>

        </div>
</script>
```

javascript controller

```
     if(comparisons.isFollowed){
       outputHTML += '<h5>Follows you</h5>';
     }
     if(!comparisons.doesFollow){
     outputHTML += "<a ng-click='followUser()' href='#' class='btn btn-success space'>Follow User</a>";  
     }else{
       outputHTML += "<button type='button' ng-click='unfollowUser' class='btn btn-warning space'>Unfollow User</button>";
     }
     if(!comparisons.areFriends){
       outputHTML += "<button type='button' ng-click='friendRequest'  class='btn btn-success space'>Send friend request.</button>";  
     }else if(comparisons.hasRequest){
       if(comparisons.sentRequest == currentUser){
       outputHTML += "<button type='button' ng-click='cancelRequest'  class='btn btn-warning space'>Cancel friend request.</button>";    
       }else{
         outputHTML += "<button type='button' ng-click='acceptRequest'  class='btn btn-success space'>Accept friend request</button>";
         outputHTML += "<button type='button' ng-click='declineRequest'  class='btn btn-warning space'>Decline friend request</button>";
       }
     }
     }

     $scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml(outputHTML);


$scope.followUser = function(){
    console.log("test");
    $http({ url: '/api/v1/user/' + currentUser + '/follow/' + searchedUser, method: 'POST'}).then(function successCallback(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  };
```

Comment: How and where is the `close` function defined ?

Comment: Sorry, no i was refering to the `<a ng-click='followUser()' href='#' class='btn btn-success space'>Follow User</a>` not the Cancel Button

Comment: Angular is not aware of that HTML section you're adding through Javascript, I can tell because I used this technique some times to bootstrap angular apps inside other angular apps. What you can do is to add all those buttons to your html file and use ng-show or ng-hide to display/hide them according to those conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your HTML DOM manipulation from the controller to the HTML template - you can still drive it with the model values from the controller.

So something like

```
<a ng-click='followUser()' href='#' class='btn btn-success space' ng-if="comparisons.doesFollow">Follow User</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not assign a value to the href attribute. Doing so will change the breadcrumb on the page / reload it. Remove the href from the anchor tag as thus:

```
<a ng-click='followUser()' class='btn btn-success space'>Follow User</a>
```

and your click handler will work.

Have a look at this JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wvy37/22/

Comment: Updated my earlier answer with JSFiddle.

Comment: Thanks but this still didnt work. Possibly because its inside a ng-bind-html ? Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're creating your HTML on the fly, you need to let Angular know to bind your elements. I've only ever done this inside a directive so I'm not entirely sure about the syntax for a controller (you could easily move this whole modal into a directive btw).

Have a look at the compile service:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile